# PHP shell_exec doesn't function when calling python file

Tags: python, php, svg

I have a PHP file that uploads excel files that have data in it to the server like so:

```
session_start();
$message = '';
if(isset($_POST['uploadBtn']) && $_POST['uploadBtn'] == 'Upload')
{
        if(isset($_FILES['uploadedFile']) && $_FILES['uploadedFile']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
        {
                $fileTmpPath = $_FILES['uploadedFile']['tmp_name'];
                $fileName = $_FILES['uploadedFile']['name'];
                $fileSize = $_FILES['uploadedFile']['size'];
                $fileType = $_FILES['uploadedFile']['type'];
                $fileNameCmps = explode(".", $fileName);
                $fileExtension = strtolower(end($fileNameCmps));
                $newFileName = md5(time() . $fileName) . '.' . $fileExtension;
                $newFileName = "PreprocessedFile.xlsx";
                $allowedfileExtensions = array('xls', 'xlsx');
                if (in_array($fileExtension, $allowedfileExtensions))
                {
                        $uploadFileDir = '/var/www/html/pytm/uploaded_files/';
                        $dest_path = $uploadFileDir . $newFileName;
                        if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpPath, $dest_path))
                        {
                                $message = 'File is successfully uploaded';
                                shell_exec("python3 /var/www/html/pytm/create_dfd.py");
                                $message = "<a href='/pytm/dataflow.svg' target='_blank'>Dataflow Diagram</a>";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                $message = 'There was some error moving the file to upload directory. Please make sure the upload directory is writable by web server.';
                        }

                }
                else
                {
                        $message = 'Upload failed. Allowed file types: ' . implode(',', $allowedfileExtensions);
                }
        }
        else
        {
                $message = 'There is some error in the file upload. Please check the following error.<br>';
                $message = 'Error:' . $_FILES['uploadedFile']['error'];
        }
}
$_SESSION['message'] = $message;
header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

If a file is successfully uploaded, `shell_exec()` makes a call to the python file to run.

Python file code (create_dfd.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os

os.system("python3 /var/www/html/pytm/tm.py --dfd | dot -Tsvg -o dataflow.svg")
```

This file then calls `tm.py` which then pulls the excel file from the uploaded_files directory and processes it. `create_dfd.py` then genarates an SVG file called dataflow.

The issue that I am having is that when I upload a file in the PHP page, it generates a dataflow file whose data is from a previous excel file upload.

For example:

Consider ExcelFile1 and ExcelFile2. If my uploaded_files directory is empty (no files have been uploaded), and I uploaded ExcelFile1, no dataflow.svg file will be created. If I then ssh into server and manually run the file (`python3 create_dfd.py`) dataflow.svg is created. If I then uploaded ExcelFile2 and run it, only the old dataflow.svg will be displayed until I go back in the server and manually run `python3 create_dfd.py`.

How come shell_exec() doesn't work in PHP?

If `tm.py` needs to be shown for more clarification, I will show it. I avoided it for now since it's rather large.

FYI: This is a new issue for me that started today. The only thing I understand that could be the cause was I moved this code from 1 server to another so I had to reinstall `httpd, php, python` and all of the `pip3` packages Before this, everything was working fine. Not sure what went wrong since I didn't change any of this code.

Comment: Are you sure `python3` is in the shell's path? Try changing `python3` to `/usr/bin/python3`, or whatever the exact path is.

Comment: ```/usr/bin/python3``` is the correct path. Unfortunately, changing ```python3``` to the full path doesn't work.

Comment: How have you determined that the `dataflow.svg` is from the previous upload? Have you examined the actual file on the server, or are you relying on what you get by downloading it through a browser? In other words, how do you know the new file isn't really being created and browser is just caching the old file?

Comment: I know it is the old file because the data in dataflow.svg is from ExcelFile1. I know that because I can see the contents of ExcelFile1 prior to it being uploaded.

Comment: The file on the server is upto date as it should be. I downloaded that file too.

Comment: Which is why when I just go to the terminal and run the ```python3 create_dfd.py``` It updates with the correct file implying the uploaded file is correct. The browser isn't caching the file because I even deleted dataflow.svg and then uploaded a file from the browser. ```shell_exec()``` didn't create a new dataflow.svg. Only when I went in the terminal again and ran ```create_dfd.py``` manually, that is when ```dataflow.svg``` was created.

Comment: I suggest you add debugging lines to your Python scripts to indicate whether those lines are being reached, and checking for and logging the return codes from `tm.py` and `dot`.